# Xamarin Android - Entry with icon - SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds -- TOUCH/Click event?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to make entry with Icon on the right side.

I Use Xamarin Forms + PCL

I already implement in IOS and Android the main part.

I add icon inside entry and this is looks awesome............

But!
I need catch when user click on this icon.

In Ios i did it pretty simple....but Android .. I cannot to do it(((

Xamarin.Droid CUSTOM RENDER for entry

```
  FormsEditText editText = Control;
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(element.Image))
            {            
                Drawable d = GetDrawable(element.Image);

                switch(element.ImageAlignment)
                {
                    case ImageAlignment.Left:
                         editText.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(d, null, null, null);
                        break;

                    case ImageAlignment.Right:
                        editText.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, d, null);
                        break;
                }
            }


 private BitmapDrawable GetDrawable(string imageEntryImage)
        {
            int resID = Resources.GetIdentifier(imageEntryImage, "drawable", Context.PackageName);
            Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.GetDrawable(Context, resID);
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).Bitmap;
            var im =  new BitmapDrawable(Resources, Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bitmap, element.ImageWidth * 4, element.ImageHeight * 4, true));
            return im;
        }
```

So I need catch click/touch event on this icon.

Thank you.

Comment: In case the below solution does not work let me know so i can add an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> catch click/touch event on this icon

here is a method to get it (for example,entry with left icon ) :

in your Xamarin.Droid CUSTOM RENDER for entry

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
           //Resource.Drawable.ic_action_info is your image resId
            Control.SetCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(Resource.Drawable.ic_action_info, 0, 0, 0);
            Control.SetOnTouchListener(new OnDrawableTouchListener());
        }
    }
    public class OnDrawableTouchListener : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Views.View.IOnTouchListener
    {
        public bool OnTouch(Android.Views.View v, MotionEvent e)
        {
            if (v is EditText && e.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
            {
                EditText editText = (EditText)v;
                editText.SetCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(Resource.Drawable.ic_action_info, 0, 0, 0);
                if (editText.GetCompoundDrawables()[0] != null)
                {
                    //If the region on which i tapped is the region with the icon
                    if (e.RawX <=editText.GetCompoundDrawables()[0].Bounds.Width())
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(v.Context,"icon",ToastLength.Short).Show();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an issue in the below code where the click position is being compared with the icon position. Does this work for you?

if (e.RawX <=editText.GetCompoundDrawables()[0].Bounds.Width())